# How can I constantly get a word from a specific part of my screen in python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to make a program that takes an image from a specific part of my screen and then converts it to text. I know I should use openCV and tesseract to convert to text, but I don't understand how I can constantly feed it a specific image from my screen. The image will be changing about every 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyautogui. It has an in-build screenshot function.

```
import pyautogui

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save(r'./screenshot.png')
```

You can use a for loop in which you can save the screenshot as the 'i'th iteration.
Something like `screenshot.save((r'./screenshot'+i+'.png'))`
You might want to make a separate folder to store the screenshots to keep everything clean or you can just overwrite the image.
Then you can use OpenCV and tesseract to read the image that you just made by using the same formula as before (r'./screenshot'+i+'.png').

I should say that this may not be fast enough that it can do this every 1-2 seconds. I've still to test it, so I can't say the time it takes. As for looking at only a specific part of the screen, maybe it can be zoomed on, but if anyone has a better way to do it, please tell me and I will update the answer. Same with if you know how to make it faster.

Please tell me if you know any way that it can be improved.